# Search the index of an String in Array using Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, watchkit

A simple question but a big problem with the Apple Watch.

I am searching the index of an element in an Array. But the code gives me `nil`.

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    let temperatur = context as! String

    let SliderData = ["off", "comfort", "eco","5.0", "5.5", "6.0", "6.5"]  

    println(toString(temperatur.dynamicType))
    println(find(SliderData, "\(temperatur)") )
}
```

Comment: `find(SliderData, "\(temperatur)")` works if `temperatur` content is one of the strings in the array. When `find` returns `nil` it means that it couldn't find the element in the array, so your `temperatur` content is probably something else than one of these elements: `["off", "comfort", "eco","5.0", "5.5", "6.0", "6.5"]`.

Comment: in context is for example 6.0, so in Temperatur is also 6.0 but 
 println(find(SliderData, "\(temperatur)") ) shows nil

Comment: If it was actually "6.0" your code would work, I've tested it. See my [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/72f4e933-94a5-4385-a84b-e5f25003bd49/ce4f1e4116f91b77/res/97064f3d-0c95-4083-8c2c-d82e6f7d4dc2/skitch.png).

Comment: if i do it in your way it works, but if i get the context, put it into temperatur i will get nil for the index; in my code i wrote: 
       println(temperatur)    and    println(find(SliderData, "\(temperatur)") )   the result is 6.0 and nil

Answer (score 1):

The array does not contain the string contained in the variable "temperatur" which is why you are not getting an index back.

If the value is already a string then you don't need to use `"\(temperatur)"` You can use this line instead:

```
println(find(SliderData, temperatur) )
```

Comment: in context is for example 6.0, so in Temperatur is also 6.0 but println(find(SliderData, "(temperatur)") ) shows nil

Comment: If you use `println(temperatur)` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the string "temperatur" – which is obviously not in the array – rather than for the content of the variable `temperatur`

```
println(find(SliderData, temperatur) )
```

Comment: By using `"\(temperatur)"` Marc is actually searching for the string representation of the variable `temperatur`. Not a string with the value `"temperatur"`